# spring mvc bootsrap modal uisng spring tag library getById() and validation annotation based

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

hope u guys help me out this problem
when I try to get the getById and to do validation over bootstrap modal window get this error !! I don't what to do !1 anything wrong in code level please let me know guys

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'update' available as request attribute
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.Manage_005fTemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(Manage_005fTemplate_jsp.java:990)    at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.Manage_005fTemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(Manage_005fTemplate_jsp.java:924)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.Manage_005fTemplate_jsp._jspService(Manage_005fTemplate_jsp.java:714)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1271)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Jun 10, 2018 1:46:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context
>   with path [/eposh] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'update'
>   available as request attribute] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'update' available as request attribute
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.Manage_005fTemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(Manage_005fTemplate_jsp.java:990)    at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.Manage_005fTemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(Manage_005fTemplate_jsp.java:924)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.Manage_005fTemplate_jsp._jspService(Manage_005fTemplate_jsp.java:714)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1271)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

my Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editTemplate(@PathVariable int id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse reponse) {
   System.out.println("get by id" + id);
   ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Manage_Template");
   model.addObject("update", ts.getTemplateById(id));
   /*model.addAttribute("update", ts.getTemplateById(id));*/
   return "Manage_Template";

}
```

**My JSP :**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:80%;">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Update Template</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="box box-warning">
          <div class="box-header">

          </div>
          <div class="box-body">
            <form:form role="form" action="" method="post" id="update_form" commandName="update" modelAttribute="update">
              <section class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">


                  <form:input path="template_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name Of Template" name="template_name" />

                </div>

              </section>
              <section class="col-lg-12">

                <form:textarea id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80" path="summary" placeholder="Place some text here" name="summary" />

                <!--  </textarea> -->
              </section><br>
              <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Update Template" id="update_template_id">
              </div>


            </form:form>

          </div>





        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!---- in this JSP I am getting error -->



  <td><button onclick="editTemplate(<%=rs.getString(1)%>)" data-target="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" title="Edit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</button></td>

  <script>
    function editTemplate(id) {
      $.get("update/" + id, function(result) {
        /* $("#myModal1").modal('show') */
      });
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beacause there is missing attribute in your JSP view ,( the `update` attribute)

Also in your controller you're returning a Sting not A modelandview , So use the Model as method parameter (instead of instantiating model and view )and the append your model attribute in it , your controller should look like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String editTemplate(@PathVariable int id,
                                  Model model,
                                  HttpServletRequest request,
                                  HttpServletResponse reponse) {
        System.out.println("get by id"+id);

        model.addAttribute("update",ts.getTemplateById(id));

        return "Manage_Template";
}
```

**NOTE :** what does ts.getTemplateById(id) ? do and waht's the ts exactly (service , component ?) ?

Comment: ts.getTemplateById(id) ? ts denotes service and also above one also tried.but not getting since through same error

Comment: YOUR CLASS IS ANOTAED WITH `@Controller` or `@RestController` ? also try to surround model.attribute (...)... in try catch block